# Complete process to upload an updated app to the app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I haven't found anywhere a place that explains the process to upload an updated version of your app on the app store. Can someone guide me through the whole process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular problem you are facing while publishing an update of an app to the app store?

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new version of the app on the iTunes Connect which reflects the new version of the app.
2. Update the whats next section and screenshots on iTunes Connect for the new version.
3. Update the version number in your code
4. Submit the app to the app store

Comment: Im not facing any problem i just didn't know where to start... So in xcode i just need to change the version number and i can do the changes on the same project as the initial version?

Comment: Yes, the main thing is that you change the version number on Xcode with the same version number that you put on the iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

The whole process of uploading a new version of your app is explained here:
[Replacing your app with a new version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14)